# Refer to a file on a network drive, alternately from a Windows and a Ubuntu machine, without having to modify the path name manually?

Tags: mount, windows, latex, cifs

I'm writing a LaTeX document that in turn refers to a file that lies on a network drive of my institution. At work I use a Windows PC, but at home I use a laptop with Ubuntu (which I'm absolutely new to!) and access my document with the help of the `cifs-utils` package.

Now in order to refer to the second file from within the TeX document, I need to specify its path -- yet path names look different for Windows and Ubuntu. E.g., in Windows I use either the network drive's address such as

`\include{//network-address/folder/file.tex}`

or an assigned drive name such as

`\include{S:/folder/file.tex}`.

In turn, on Ubuntu I specify the mount point which might result in something like

`\include{~/mount-point/folder/file.tex}`.

Now in fact I do not refer to one external file, but several ones, and it would be quite cumbersome to change paths manually in the TeX document every once I change the OS I'm working at.

My question is: Could I make Ubuntu interpret the "network address" version of the path directly instead of having to call the mount point, so that I could use the same path name under Windows and Ubuntu? Or could you think of another solution that automates the process?

Comment: I would expect LaTeX to be able to put the path name in a variable, so you only have to change it once, or even read it from an environment variable or script parameter. Wouldn't http://tex.stackexchange.com be a better site to ask this question?

Comment: @Jos Thanks, you're right, I'm sure LaTeX could do that. But I was hoping I could fully automate the process (without me even having to [un]comment a single line), and I was wondering specifically if Ubuntu could, similar to Windows, interpret the "real" network address, hence my question here. In turn, if LaTeX could detect the OS, I might define the path variable depending on the OS. I haven't looked into that, I'll admit; so tex.SE could be my friend.